# Convert a .png file to a GeoTIFF while knowing the boundings

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, convert, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

*Disclaimer*: I've already found this link [Convert PNG to GeoTiff using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118180/convert-png-to-geotiff-using-gdal) - but it was of no help.

Actually I've got a `.png` file of a hand-drawn map (I also got it in the `.svg` format in case this may help).
I currently know the exact boundings of this file:

```
   {
     ne: { lat: 48.506161, lng: -1.714582 },
     sw: { lat: 48.477861, lng: -1.742703 }
   }
```

It's located in the north of France.

So here's the command I tried so far with `gdal_translate`:

```
 gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'
 -a_ullr 48.506161 -1.714582 48.477861 -1.742703 myfile.png output.tif
```

My final goal is to serve this file under a tiles system (`x/y/z.png`) for Leaflet or OpenLayers.
So I used `gdal2tiles` to convert the output.tif file:

```
sudo gdal2tiles.py -p mercator output.tif  result/
```

But my problem is that the generated tiles are geolocated in the north of Madagascar instead of France. Any clue on this?

Comment: your axes are the wrong way round - try to change the -a_srs to epsg:4326

Comment: Thank you for helping me, Ian! If the new command you proposed is : __gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 48.506161 -1.714582 48.477861 -1.742703 myfile.png output.tif__, then I got exactly the same result - or is there anything else I must do?

Comment: I'd try dal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -1.714582 48.506161 -1.742703 48.477861 myfile.png output.tif

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. Too bad, I was so close for the good result... Do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: I'll add a longer answer to help future users out.

Comment: This time the source data is explicit and defines the meaning of coordinates `ne: { lat: 48.506161, lng: -1.714582 }` but user should also know that GDAL is always taking coordinates in order longitude-latitude or easting-northing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that your map appears at Madagascar and not France is the clue here. It means that your axes are swapped (Madagascar is about as far south as France is West). So you need to switch round the order of the coordinates in your bounding box (and I would use the shorter EPSG:4326 instead of the proj4 string).

So your command becomes

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -1.714582 48.506161 -1.742703 48.477861 myfile.png output.tif
```